# Bubbling the Dom of Jquery

Tags: jquery

My problem here I know is bubbling within the DOM because I have multiple pages inside of my pagination and when I click on a edit class link multiple times it bubbles and loads the same file continuously and I'm wanting to know a better way to solve this.

```
$('.edit').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var contentPageID = $(this).attr('id');
     $('div.right_content').load('modules/forms/edit/contentpages.php?contentPageID=' + contentPageID);
});
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question. do you want the link to stop functioning after the first click or is the event happening more than once due to some sort of event bubbling/propagation?

Comment: the event happening more than once due to some sort of event bubbling/propagation, however the answer by ShankarSangoli worked with my code.

Comment: Is it possible that you are attaching the event more than once? Can you post the html that this event is attaching too?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/yGmxh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

and

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var b = 0;

$('.edit').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   if(b==0){
    var contentPageID = $(this).attr('id');
     $('div.right_content').load('modules/forms/edit/contentpages.php?contentPageID=' + contentPageID);
}
b++;
});
```

Comment: what happens next time they click it? all in all seems like a bad idea to have a global variable to prevent bubbling.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent multiple executions of the `click` event, [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) it after the first time:

```
$( '.edit' ).live( 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var contentPageID = $(this).attr('id');
    $( 'div.right_content').load('modules/forms/edit/contentpages.php?contentPageID=' + contentPageID);
    $('.edit').unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: Tried it but still did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.edit').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var contentPageID = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('div.right_content').data("currentPage") != contentPageID){
     $('div.right_content').data("currentPage", contentPageID).load('modules/forms/edit/contentpages.php?contentPageID=' + contentPageID, 
    function(){
       $('div.right_content').data("currentPage", null);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried all of them and this is the 1 that worked with my code. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this answer is if the users quickly hits page 1 then 2, page 2 will not load, because 1 is loading.

Comment: Yeah it didn't work because when I went to a different module it loads the content pages module instead of the oen I clicked on.

Comment: Is there a different way of coding it easier.

Comment: Looking at your requirement I think this is the right way to do it.

Comment: This answer just covers up the problem in my opinion. Something is causing the click event to go off more than once, this is just preventing the additional times from doing anything. You should figure out why the event is going off more than once.

Comment: Can we talk about this in a chat?

Comment: Can you send me an IM on yahoo if you have it. (Xtremer360).